# Cometd connect request(AJAX) not working with IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, dojo, cometd

I have an application which publishes notification from server to all channels using `COMETD`. It works fine with chrome and FF but not with the IE. In IE8 sometimes it works after a manual refresh(F5) of page. In fiddler it is showing connect request going to Bayeux server.

Connect Request:-

> [{"id":"226","successful":true,"advice":{"interval":2000,"reconnect":"retry","multiple-clients":true,"timeout":30000},"channel":"/meta/connect"}]

Is this a configuration issue or AJAX connect request not working with IE8 ??

Comment: it always shows reconnect:retry with successful:true ?

Answer (score 0):

The `meta/connect` response that you posted shows that IE8 works and was able to receive the response.

The `multiple-clients` advice is probably due to you performing manual refreshes, see the [related documentation](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#java_server_multiple_sessions).

You are too vague about what works and what does not, so it's difficult to help you further, but a `multiple-clients` advice will cause at worst a 2000 ms latency on your server-to-client messages.

You may want to use the [reload extension](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#extensions_reload) to avoid the refresh problem.

Other than that, IE8 should work like all the other browsers.